# Pick a text file using default file picker in Android versions above Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

In the past versions Android hadn't any default filemanager but in the version of Android above Lollipop I have seen there is some sort of very basic filemanager to pick file that appears when you use `startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE)`.

For the pictures I have used successful

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData())
```

to load the picked image file from the Intent data object returned after `onActivityResult` invocation

But I don't know how to get the correct path for other file types e.g. txt files.
This task now should be possible without using additional libraries or file managers.

Comment: "there is some sort of very basic filemanager to pick file that appears when you use startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE)" -- well, that would depend entirely on what `intent` is. "I don't know how to get the correct path for other file types" -- if you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you are not working with files. You are working with content, and you will get a `content` `Uri` back. You can work with those via `ContentResolver` (e.g., `openInputStream()`).

Comment: could you give me a sample or some better way to use that kind of default filemanager to get file path?

Comment: "could you give me a sample" -- give you a sample of *what*? "some better way to use that kind of default filemanager to get file path" -- that is not possible, other than by making a copy of the content to some file that you control. A `content` `Uri` is akin to an `https` `Uri`. You cannot "get file path" for an `https` `Uri`, but you can download the content to some file that you control.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I ask you to get the content of a generic file without use any library in newer Android version what you would write?

Comment: I would use an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` `Intent` with `startActivityForResult()`. Then, with the `content` `Uri` delivered to `onActivityResult()`, I would use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok but to open a file that isn't registered as a common type e.g. an encrypted file with no known format what you would use?

Comment: I would use the same thing, with a wildcard MIME type.